# Systemd "No such file or directory" itself during "docker-compose up"

Tags: docker-compose, systemd

I have a project with Docker on Ubuntu Server where I wish run my containers every system restart so that, I decided use systemd. I have next file with configuration

```
[Unit]
Description=My Server container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
User=adminuser
Group=vpsusers
Restart=always
Environment=PROJECT=/home/adminuser/project/docker-compose.yml
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ${PROJECT} up
Execop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ${PROJECT} down

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run service locally on server is executed successfully but when it happens a system reboot cannot call service.

My error is:

```
docker-compose[3306]: .IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/adminuser/project/docker-compose.yml'
```

Unfortunately is my first experience with Systemd, I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear. Are you sure this file `/home/adminuser/project/docker-compose.yml` exists?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous exists file, because I run the service in server successfully but when the system is reboot cannot run service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I detected why my service cannot find the directory is because my directory home was encrypted then "root" cannot access. I recommend review every step during installation S.O. in a server.